# Javascript HTML5 player - Add stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I built an HTML5/jQuery player at some point last year and upon going back to it, I had a question about what to do when the audio source no longer exists, or if the song has finished.

So, when using a local mp3 file, for example: 'song.mp3', when that finishes, is there a way to make the player itself reset and have the play button reinstated? As it is now, the player will just follow javascript instruction and will (to my knowledge) require two clicks to get it started again because that is it's logic.

Or, if using a remote source, such as a SHOUTcast stream (http://somedomain.com:8000/;stream.nsv), if or when that source drops (either because of a streaming problem or because the source has actually disconnected (like in a SHOUTcast broadcast)), is there a way to try to reconnect and if it hasn't after 5 or 10 seconds, say, could we then reset the player?

This is purely curiosity - I've yet to give anything a try. But, if it can be done, then kudos to the person that helps me because this could be great if it does.

Live view of a working player here: http://www.dominicharrison.co.uk/projects/audio-player/original

**Note the audio plays on load!**

JS code:

```
/* Coded and designed by D Harrison */
$(document).ready(function(){

    var audioPlayer = document.getElementById("audio-player");
    //var audioSrc =  'http://habbcrazy.net:8000/;stream.nsv';
    var audioSrc =  'song.mp3';
    var prevValue = '0';

    audioPlayer.src = audioSrc;
    audioPlayer.play();


$("#play").click(function(){

        if (audioPlayer.paused) {
               audioPlayer.src = audioSrc;
               $("#slider").slider('value', $("#slider").slider('value') + prevValue);
               audioPlayer.play();
               prevValue = '0';
            }   
            else {
               audioPlayer.pause();
               audioPlayer.src ='';
               prevValue = $("#slider").slider('value');
               $("#slider").slider('value', $("#slider").slider('value') - 100);
            }

            $(this).toggleClass('inactive'); 
            return false;
        })

        $("#slider").slider(
        {   value: 75,
            step: 0.1,
            range: 'min',
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            slide: function(){
                var value = $("#slider").slider('value');
                audioPlayer.volume = (value / 100);
                $( "#amount" ).text($( "#slider" ).slider( "value") + '%');
            },
            change: function(){
                var value = $("#slider").slider('value');
                audioPlayer.volume = (value / 100);
                $( "#amount" ).text($( "#slider" ).slider( "value") + '%');
            },
            animate: true
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> So, when using a local mp3 file, for example: 'song.mp3', when that finishes, is there a way to make the player itself reset and have the play button reinstated? As it is now, the player will just follow javascript instruction and will (to my knowledge) require two clicks to get it started again because that is it's logic.

You can put a handler on the "ended" event. In jQuery it would be:

```
$(audio).on("ended",function(){
  //reset audio track and play button here
}
```

> Or, if using a remote source, such as a SHOUTcast stream (http://somedomain.com:8000/;stream.nsv), if or when that source drops (either because of a streaming problem or because the source has actually disconnected (like in a SHOUTcast broadcast)), is there a way to try to reconnect and if it hasn't after 5 or 10 seconds, say, could we then reset the player?

There's other audio events to play with. I haven't used all of them, but test for "waiting" or "progress" or something of that type. [HTML Audio/Video Events](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

Comment: Ah, brilliant. Thanks! Will give it a look over and report back!